# Using OpenGL 2.1 within VM

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, virtual-machine

I recently switched over to the new Parallels Desktop Version from VMWare. I am working on MacOSX and develop with Visual Studio (C++), because I have to do an OpenGL Windows Game for my University Coursework. The problem is that the header/library files of OpenGL are only OpenGL 1.1, so I can't work on my FXAA GLSL Shader implementation.
The Windows VM has a certain Parallels Destop specific driver for the graphics, as far as I know, so is there a way to get the OpenGL2.1 features working within the VM?

Comment: [Mesa](http://www.mesa3d.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use OpenGL>1.1 on Windows, you need to use [GLee](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/libs/GLee/), [GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/) or similar library.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to find out if the Parallels drivers for Windows which are provided support OpenGL 2.1.